# Cannot Install Google Chrome. How do I fix it?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I can't install Google Chrome browser. I wonder why and how to fix it. Here is the log I got from my terminal when installing Google Chrome.

```
$ sudo dpkg --install chrome.deb
[sudo] password for young: 
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 141861 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from chrome.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0); however:
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3); however:
  Package libnss3-1d is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libxss1; however:
  Package libxss1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 140 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 141960 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-chrome-stable ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...

$ sudo dpkg --install chrome.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 141861 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from chrome.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0); however:
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3); however:
  Package libnss3-1d is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libxss1; however:
  Package libxss1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

It does not work in GUI too. Look at what I have got:

[image: on GUI]

Comment: same problem and none of the below answers seem to work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You probably need to enable the "universe" repository.

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Once you enable it, update your system and you should now be able to install `google-chrome-stable`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1
```

Answer (score 76):

You can fix this by installing missing dependencies.
Just run the following command
(after you have run `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb`).

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will install missing dependencies and configure Google Chrome for you.

Comment: Read the question. That is exactly what OP is doing and that is what the question is about...

Comment: This saved my buns. yay

Comment: works great, just add that you need to  run the installation two times

Answer (score 11):

Why not just install Chromium from the Ubuntu repos?

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

That simple!

Comment: at the moment this is an older version, packaged with a lot of security bugs already fixed in the Google-branded version.

Comment: I won't want to install chromium browser, since it is not as stable and mostly for developers.

Comment: I've found it to be quite stable.  It's essentially just like Chrome.

Comment: I would not have known that.  How would one know when to use apt-get and when not to do so?

Comment: Always use apt-get to install things unless there's a really good reason not to.

Comment: One example where you want `chrome` and not `chromium`:  If you already have some paid subscription which works under Windows+TV+Smartphone, you probably want to access this under Linux as well, right?  In that case it is likely that `chrome` comes with everything you need right out of the box.  It also provides easy updates.  Unlike `chromium` which is unsupported by the subscription most of the time and often difficult to keep updated (read: to keep safe) due to all those tweaks applied (think of Flash, DRM, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Running `apt --fix-broken install` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1`

Post any error output here.  If no errors, `sudo dpkg -i chrome.deb` again afterwards and you should be good.

Comment: Hello, thx for your reply. I got a few error messages : http://pastebin.com/CYeCMWiE

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw this error and I was able to resolve it using the following:

```
apt-get install libcurl3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used this to fix it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And then, try to install Google Chrome again.