# How do you install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, 16.04

The software installer just hangs with a ? icon and from command line it says:

```
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ... 
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ... 
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ... 
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ... 
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... 
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing:  google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has been answered in the past, here's a reference.

Refer to:
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220960/cannot-install-google-chrome-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'd guess so, I'm still on 15.10 and haven't upgraded to 16.04 yet, but I sure can't wait to do so. It's either that or google's newest version of chrome ended up being broken by something Ubuntu updated or vice-versa.

Answer (score 69):

[This](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/02/install-google-chrome-4802564116-on.html) worked for me
 (all other methods suggested got me very lost):

Download the package (**64 bit**):

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Install the package, forcing install of dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

In case any dependencies didn't install (you would have a warning or failure message for this), you can force them via:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Note: Refer to the link above for 32 bit systems.

Comment: Please share the detail as well. There is not guarantee the link work later. It is always better to put the core of the solution and share the link to the original source for more detail and reference.

Comment: Ive submitted an edit that just copies the steps from the provided link.

Comment: For me, with Ubuntu 16.04, it works with just the first two steps, without 'sudo apt-get install -f'

Comment: Same as @YuShen, neither need `--force-depends`.

Answer (score 6):

Simple steps - 
1. Search for and install 'Gdebi Package Installer' from ubuntu app store
2. Right click the downloaded Google Chrome .deb file and select 'Open with' and then click 'Gdebi Package Installer'
3. Done! :-)

Gdebi will automatically fetch the missing dependencies for you

Answer (score 4):

This is the answer that worked for me:

Simple steps:

1. Search for and install `Gdebi Package Installer` from the ubuntu Software Center.
2. Download google chrome https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/
3. Right click the downloaded Google Chrome `.deb` file and select 'Open with' and then click 'Gdebi Package Installer'
4. Done! :-)

Gdebi will automatically fetch the missing dependencies for you.

So I just want to tell exactly what I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi

$ gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

P.S.: I was in the Downloads folder when I did this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download latest version from https://www.google.com/chrome/
2. Move to the folder that contains the file, via GUI or terminal (like `cd ~/Downloads`)

Install the package by clicking on it, or via the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

If you have issues, you may have to run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

After downloading the  `.deb` package I ran these commands first:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1
```

and then change the terminal working directory to the downloaded file location
(like `cd ~/Downloads`) and then install `Chrome` using this command on terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

It worked for me.